# ASP.NET C# - Excel Sheet to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

So, I have to export an Excel file, open it and to run a Macro that will format the Excel and I want to use it as a DataTable.
I can't transform my file to a DataTable since it is already uploaded and I can't use the one that I uploaded from the file Upload

I tried many things which they didn't work, like using various classes that I already have, but they only work for file upload files and not files like I am doing, the sheet after the vba macro.

```
var obj = Server.MapPath(upload_ficheiro.FileName);
            //~~> Define your Excel Objects
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

            //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(obj);

            //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("Audit");



            //~~> Clean-up: Close the workbook
            xlWorkBook.Close(false);

            //~~> Quit the Excel Application
            xlApp.Quit();
```

My code is like that and I tried various classes of my web application to transform it to a DataTable, imagine, I want to make it a datatable after the sheet is ran with the vba macro, which is only 1 sheet and 1 macro.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Microsoft [have this to say on server-side automation of Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) - _"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."_

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).